# How do I properly alias a has_many through a join in Rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Rails/ActiveRecord newbie here.  Consider the following models for a Classroom, User and ClassroomEnrollments (join between the two)

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fulltime_enrollments, -> { where(duration: 'full-time') }, class_name: "ClassroomEnrollments"
  has_many :fulltimers, :through => :fulltime_enrollments, class_name: "User"

  has_many :parttime_enrollments, -> { where(duration: 'part-time') }, class_name: "ClassroomEnrollments"
  has_many :parttimers, :through => :parttime_enrollments, class_name: "User"
end

class ClassroomEnrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns: user_id, classroom_id, duration
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :classroom
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classroom_enrollments
  has_many :classrooms, :through => :classroom_enrollments
end
```

The following model for a classroom and classroom_enrollments does not work.  Specifically the `:fulltimers` and `:parttimers` aliases throw `undefined method 'to_sym' for nil:NilClass` errors when I try to access them via `my_classroom.fulltimers` or `my_classroom.parttimers`.

If I remove the `:parttimers` alias and rename `:fulltimers` to `:users` it works fine (and displays only the full time students), so it seems to me that it has something to do with it figuring out that `:fulltimers` is of type `User`, even though I've specified the `classname: "User"` in the `has_many` condition.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the source association cannot be inferred automatically, you need specify it using the `:source` option:

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many(
    :fulltime_enrollments, 
    -> { where(duration: 'full-time') }, 
    class_name: "ClassroomEnrollments"
  )
  has_many :fulltimers, :through => :fulltime_enrollments, :source => :user

  has_many(
    :parttime_enrollments, 
    -> { where(duration: 'part-time') }, 
    class_name: "ClassroomEnrollments"
  )
  has_many :parttimers, :through => :parttime_enrollments, :source => :user
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many-source

How about trying a cleaner, more readable approach? Something like this:

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classroom_enrollments
  has_many :users, through: :classroom_enrollments

  def full_timers
    users_by_duration("full-time")
  end

  def part_timers
    users_by_duration("part-time")
  end

  private

  def users_by_duration(duration)
    users.where(classroom_enrollments: { duration: duration })
  end
end
```

Then:

```
my_classroom = Classroom.find(1)
my_classroom.full_timers
```

Comment: does this still provides something like `my_classroom.full_timers << user_object` ?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this while working on something similar. This is will generate the same sql and is a bit easier to look at.

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classroom_enrollments
  has_many :users, through: :classroom_enrollments

  def fulltimers
    users.merge(ClassroomEnrollment.full_time)
  end

  def parttimers
    users.merge(ClassroomEnrollment.part_time)
  end
end

class ClassroomEnrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :classroom

  scope :fulltime, ->{ where(duration: 'full-time') }
  scope :parttime, ->{ where(duration: 'part-time') }
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classroom_enrollments
  has_many :classrooms, :through => :classroom_enrollments
end
```